# If matrix $A,B$ have null determinant, then there exists a matrix $X$ such that $AX = XB = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

Suppose we have $A, B \in M_{n,n}\left(\mathbb{C}\right)$ such that $\det A = \det B = 0$.
Prove that there exists $X \neq 0 \in M_{n,n}\left(\mathbb{C}\right)$ s.t. $AX = XB = 0$

My idea on how to prove this was the following:
Because $\det A = 0 = \det B = \det B^T$, all those matrix have $0$ as an eigenvalue and as such let's denote $V_A, V_T$ the set eigenvectors of $A,B^T$ relative to $0$.

Now, if we show that we can construct a matrix $X$ with elements of $V_A$ as columns and elements of $V_T$ as rows we are set.

This is because $AX = \left(AX^1, \dots, AX^n\right) = \left(0, \dots, 0\right) = 0$ and, with $X_* := X^T, XB = \left(B^TX_*\right)^T = \left(B^TX_*^1, \dots, B^TX_*^n\right)^T = \left(0, \dots, 0\right)^T = 0$

What I'm missing is how to formalize that such a matrix can always be constructed: my idea was that, in the worst case, i have $0$ "intersections" between the basis of $V_A$ and of $V_T$:
for example let's suppose that
$$V_A = Span\left(\left(\begin{matrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{matrix}\right)\right), V_T = Span\left(\left(\begin{matrix}0 \\ 1 \\ 1\end{matrix} \right)\right)$$ then I can simply define a function $f$ which resolves the problem of mismatches.

What i mean is $X$ relative to the case explained before would be $$X = f\left(V_A,V_B\right) = \left(\begin{matrix}  0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{matrix}\right)$$

More in general, one could think of such a procedure in this way.
Let $v_T$ be a vector in $V_T$, and define $I_T$ the set of the index s.t. $v_T^i \neq 0$. Do the same with $v_A \in V_A$ and the set $I_A$

Now, consider $i \in I_T^C$: set all columns $X^i = 0$.
Do the same with the rows of $X$ considering $j \in I_A^C$
Now fill the remaining positions in a way that respects your vectors: we have thus created an $X$ s.t. it's rows are eigenvectors of $B^T$ and its columns are eigenvectors of $A$.

Comment: Do you want $X$ to be invertible? Otherwise, just pick the zero matrix.

Comment: Do you want $AX=XB=0$ or $AX=BX=0$ ?? The title does not match the question.

Answer (score 2):

You probably have to ensure $rank{X} \geq 1$, do to so you just take $y \in \ker A$ and $z \in \ker B^T$, you have your matrix:
$$X = y z^T$$

Then $AX = Ay z^T = 0\cdot z^T = 0 = y\cdot 0 = y (B^T z)^T = yz^T B$

Comment: And there exists $y \neq 0, z \neq 0$ because $A,B$ have the determinant equal to 0, so they are not invertible and therefore by rank nullity theorem their Kernel must at least have dimension 1.

Comment: exactly and $\det B^T  = \det B$